# Do I need to replace the springs on my front disc brakes?

Tags: ford, brake-rotor

I just disassembled the front brake caliper (dual piston) on my 1974 Ford F250 390 V8.

There was a spring on each of the caliper bolts in between the brake pads. The springs are really rusty and one of them broke in half.

Looking on O'Reilly's site, I can't find replacement springs. Are these in use anymore? If so, what are they called? Where should I look for a new set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to say yes, you should replace those springs, especially the broken one....

Some [Googling](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&rls=com.microsoft%3a%2a&biw=1259&bih=773&tbm=shop&q=1974%20Ford%20F250%20brake%20caliper%20springs&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=) indicates that springs fitting your description are still in use and you should be able to mail order them.

Comment: Wow $12 for one set of springs.... Thanks for the info. Think I'll check some of my local shops first though...

Comment: @Jeremy, absolutely support your local economy.  It helps to know what to ask for and how much it should cost before you hit the shops, though.  I'm a slave to Amazon Prime, myself - it's hard to turn your nose up at free shipping of crazy heavy equipment.

Answer (score 1):

Your local NAPA store can order them.  It is part number UP 82116A and contains springs for both wheels.

Comment: I did end up finding them at Winchester Auto Parts (local chain). Just needed to know what to ask for :-)